# Visual studio is waiting for internal operation to complete

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have problem with my Visual studio 2013 Ultimate from few days. I'm trying to open even simplest console application and VS hangs and when I click something else in Visual studio in the bottom right corner shows up **Visual studio is busy: Microsoft Visual studio is waiting for internal operation to complete.**

I have repaired Visual studio no change, then unistall and install fresh VS and the problem is still there. I also checked for viruses. Everything else in Windows is working properly. I have disabled CodeLens, changed current source control plug-in to None because I found that sometimes this two options hangs vs but there is still no change.

Comment: Enable logging in VS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) to check where it's hanging.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For VS2015 users who are dealing with this problem: close everything, delete the ".vs" folder on the project root and reopen it.

Comment: This helps, but I have to delete the .vs folder everytime before I open the solution. Isn't there another solution or an explanation where this problem comes from? It's really annoying...

Comment: I even re-installed Visual Studio 2015 but was still same..However, just deleting the ".vs" folder which contain .suo file solved this problem..".vs" folder is located in each project you're working..Thank you guys !

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm using VS2015 shell for SSDT. Almost everytime I touch a UI control I see the message

Comment: worked like a charm ..Microsoft should look into it.

Comment: You saved  my day. Had a tough time finding a solution  This  is applicable for VS2019 too

Answer (score 8):

There are also some steps, like to clean different cache you can follow, but it hasn't solved my problem… [Check this blog post](http://nitindhiman.blogspot.dk/2015/01/microsoft-visual-studio-is-busy-waiting.html).

The important part of it:

> There could be many reasons behind this. Few common fixes are below:
>
> 1. Remove website cache from following location:
>      C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
> 2. Restart IIS: Start → RUN → iisreset
> 3. Go to Tools → Options and browse all the options and disable all
>      unnecessary options.
> 4. Clear cache.
> 5. Remove temp files.
> 6. Ensure there is enough space in C (System) drive.

**Update 2017-01-03** 
There are also **ASP.NET caches** in *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET framework* folders, but this is rather for website or debug cache problems. When in the mentioned folder, search for *"Temporary ASP.NET Files"* in sub-directories and delete their content. If some files are locked, then *iisreset* should help.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is fixed ... I make new console project and waited twenty minutes to actually create the project. After creation now every project opens immediately without any problem.

Comment: For me the **solution** was to delete the `.suo file`, Check [this](http://www.davidspot.com/post/2016/02/10/fix-microsoft-visual-studio-is-busy-waiting-for-an-internal-operation-to-complete) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/800176/visual-studio-ultimate-2013-hangs-with-waiting-for-operation-to-complete-messa) post and follow steps one by one if none works then try to delete the `.suo file` , hope helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when trying to load Xamarin project. Regretfully, deleting *.suo file, as well as other answers mentioned here, did not help.

The solution was to reset Visual Studio settings, as described at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/

> Delete the contents from the following folders:
>
> - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
> - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
> - C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
>
> Go to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and Run the following command “devenv /resetuserdata” from the Visual Studio IDE folder:
>   * Typical location for 64 bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
>   * Typical location for 32 bit: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Be careful, as you will lose all your project settings

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem in my Win10 PC, then I just fixed it by install Visual Studio update in Tools → Extension → Update → Visual studio 2013 update 5.

After I installed the "Visual studio 2013 Update 5", the problem has gone.

Answer (score 2):

From [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/800176/visual-studio-ultimate-2013-hangs-with-waiting-for-operation-to-complete-messa), delete the .suo (.vs12.suo for me) file from the solution directory. Worked for me in VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

delete project, move to another destinition.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I deleted my .suo and .tss temp files, then tried again. In the past I had created a new blank SLN, and added my projects back to it - that also works.

Comment: What are .tss files and where do you find them?

Comment: it turns out they are 'tab studio' files - a VS tab extension. - not related to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've had two things cause this beside the suo/vs folder thing:

1. A project is checked in with references to files that aren't checked in. For example, a code generator project with T4 templates that spit out 1000 poco's. The .cs files were never meant to be source controlled, but someone accidentally checks in the project with the file includes.
2. A .csproj merges funny and instead of failing to load the individual project, the entire solution hangs

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with many projects. Last night I added a new project to the solution. This morning, the VS15 IDE would freeze up with this error after loading my solution. I tried many of the suggestions in this thread, but none seemed to work.

I removed the new project from the solution, and now everything is working fine. Something must have been corrupted or just plain wrong in my .csproj file. Once it was removed from the .sln everything seemed to work fine again. Now I'll rebuild the new project.

Answer (score 0):

For whats its worth, I remember working with a project that was using git source control, and we discovered that visual studios git client was causing the whole environment to run really really slowly, probably because the project was very large.

Go to Tools->Options->Source Control->Plug-in selection-> Select None from the list.

This improved things greatly for me in the past, hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when updating a SSIS package using VS 2008,

Solution: Open the dtsx file, search all the timeouts and change them to something like 10 seconds, for some reason some of them where 0, which basically means: 'hang forever'.

Answer (score 0):

:)

For this issue, there is no any exact solution. from my experience, there can be 
lots of reasons for this error. you might fixed this by doing

1 ) deleting the .vs folder in the project file

2 ) Removing the web cache at
    C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

3) Clearing the temp files

4) Update/Upgrade or re-installing the vs :(

But, Still you might not found the solution, then the next step should be

**UNINSTALL YOU ANTI VIRUS PROGRAM**

```
 specially if you are using Bit Defender / 
 McAfee most probably that will be the reason for the issue ( in my case is 
 was McAfee) 

 If it doesn't work,

 Go for **System restore** 
 (better solution than re-installing the visual studio )

 I solved this issue after uninstalling McAfee anti-virus program.

 Hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this problem sometime in WPF Projects, You should just close `XAML Designer` process in task manager and after that click the `Enable project code` button in XAML Designer tab in Visual Studio. By doing that you'll continue working without closing visual studio.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when I installed Wix Extension, so while opening wix type of project I was getting this error. I just restarted the machine and opened the solution again and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened with me because the large number of code lines in one function
(more than two thousand line ) I divided my code to many function
then every thing worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone mentioning this file "N2000-VS2015.VC.db".  Maybe, I missed it from the reading.  This file grows over time, for me > 600 MB.  Maybe, in addition to the .suo and other files, delete this file and reopen the project.  Deleting this file seems to work for me.

Answer (score -3):

**The problem**

This issue arises when the Data-source is a View that SELECTs from the results of other Views.

What happens is that the routine that calculates which columns supplied by the View gets confused.

**The solution to the problem**

Create a stored procedure that:

- Creates a temporary table
- INSERTs the View results into the temporary table
- SELECTs from the temporary table

This enables the Data-flow routine to calculate which columns are supplied by the View.

**How I found the solution**

I found this answer while creating a new data flow task using Visual Studio 2010's data-source assistant.

I ensured I would not experience network issues between the database and the application by hosting them on the same server.

The view in question was based on 2 other views, which were pointing to multiple tables over multiple databases.

The SSIS pkg was created by a windows account that is also server admin in Sql, but I think SSIS is just incapable of validating the data from such a complex View.

Answer (score -3):

Not a great issue! Just restart your OS, whoooo Solved, every thing works smooth. This happens if we try to open more than one projects at a time.