# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when typing code in a large C# file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, freeze

I've already seen this question: [Visual studio is waiting for internal operation to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530530/visual-studio-is-waiting-for-internal-operation-to-complete) so please don't mark this as a duplicate.

I have a large C# code file that seeds a database with about 2000 location entities and 1000 category entities. This file necessarily has several thousand variables declared. Whenever I try to type any more code into this file, Visual Studio hangs with the message: **Visual studio is busy: Microsoft Visual studio is waiting for internal operation to complete.**

This only happens when typing in code in this particular large file, e.g. if I type `string`, and then hit space, Visual Studio freezes. Because `string` and a space will be immediately be underlined with a red squiggly line and an error until you finish the code statement, is it possible that this might have something to do with the static type checker not being able to handle large files, or some other natural limit or bug?

Things I've tried so far:

- Deleting the ".vs" folder on the project root
- Delete the .suo file in the project root
- Repairing Visual Studio
- Reinstalling Visual Studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3.

Comment: Why do you put so many classes in a single file?

Comment: Might it be caused by the EF Model Designer? It freezes VS when regenerating entity classes and the more entities in the model the longer it takes. It also periodically performs autosaving which locks up VS.

Comment: @DannyChen not classes, variables. They're just string variables that get used in seeding the database with location and category entities.

Comment: @Dai perhaps? I'm seeding the database using Code First and Entity Framework 6. It only freezes when I try to type new code into this one large file.

Comment: There is no reason to have thousands of variables. If you need that, your design is badly flawed. At the very least, reduce them by putting what you can into arrays or lists. VS is telling you that you have a severe problem with your code and you need to listen and do some major refactoring.

Comment: @KenWhite that's a good point. But I've just tried commenting out some of the file and this error still occurs. Can files become corrupted? Any other thoughts?

Comment: C# source files are text, so if it was corrupted you'd already know about it. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite that's what I thought! What about the project or solution?

Comment: The project/solution are *also* text files... you can view them in notepad if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio was choking on the size of the Seed method. I've split the contents of this method into several methods in separate files. I've also reduced the number of string variables in each method. I actually didn't need to declare lots of string variables, since each one was used only once in a row in an `AddOrUpdate`, but for various reasons I felt they enhanced accuracy and readability.

Just another reminder that our hardware and software still have serious limits. Here's to the future.

Comment: Data != Code. Data doesn't *belong* in code. *That's* the takeaway here.

Comment: @Mat'sMug serious question: If I don't seed the database from code, what are some other options? I could go the way of SQL scripts, but I found that approach just added complexity. This file is technically a code file (with all the advantages that entails), but in practice it's really just a big data file. What approach do you normally take to seeding lots of data?

Comment: You could have the seeding data in some xml or csv (Excel?) file(s), and your `Seed()` method could load or deserialize the data from the file(s) and populate the database with very little code.

Comment: I'm lazy, so I just make a table in Excel and make a formula to concatenate the columns into an `INSERT INTO` SQL statement; then I select the whole column, paste it into SSMS, run the script and call it a day :-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Great ideas. I actually initially organised the original location and category data into text files anyway, probably could have saved some time by just arranging and processing those. Thanks!